# How to check whether a fixed bug reported at Launchpad would affect my distro release?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, repository, launchpad, release-management

Could you please help me to decide whether this bug affects Ubuntu 12.04?

I found out [the information about the **indicator-multiload**](https://askubuntu.com/a/40019/19753) (which turned out to be the thing I have been missing in my installation of Ubuntu 12.04 for Toshiba AC100), but then I saw the comment warning about [this memory leak bug (reported at Launchpad)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-multiload/+bug/779717).

I've read the comments there, seen that some fix has been comitted, but I can't understand whether this fix got into the repository for Ubuntu 12.04, so that I can install this indiciator without being afraid of this memory leak. What is the quick way to check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between comments 37 and 38 are messages about how the bug's status in unity in Ubuntu went to Fix Released on May 31, 2011.

- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS was released before that, and likely doesn't have the fix. If the bug were to be fixed in 10.04 LTS, it would probably be tracked separately for that release. (That doesn't mean the bug is in 10.04 LTS; another possibility is that the bug simply never affected 10.04 LTS, having been introduced after that. I have not looked into that question, since that specific information is probably not important to your needs.)
- Ubuntu 11.04 was released before that, and does not have the fix. Status of the bug in unity in Ubuntu is tracked separately for that release and has the Triaged status rather than the Fix Released status.
- Ubuntu 11.10 was released about 5 months after the bug's status went to Fix Released. So the fix was incorporated into that release.
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS was released about 11 months after the bug's status went to Fix Released. So the fix was incorporated into that release, too.

Thus, **the fix should be incorporated into Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, even if no updates have been installed**.